# Ошибка при инициализации RBAC

Tags: yii2

переношу базу, миграции сделал, все ок.

но не могу заново инициализировать роли:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: yii\console\Application::user'

in /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(77): yii\base\Component->__get('user')
#1 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yii2mod/yii2-rbac/controllers/AssignmentController.php(55): yii\di\ServiceLocator->__get('user')
#2 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): yii2mod\rbac\controllers\AssignmentController->init()
#3 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(86): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#4 [internal function]: yii\base\Controller->__construct('assignment', Object(yii2mod\rbac\Module), Array)
#5 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(375): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#6 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('yii2mod\\rbac\\co...', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(345): yii\di\Container->get('yii2mod\\rbac\\co...', Array)
#8 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(642): yii\BaseYii::createObject('yii2mod\\rbac\\co...', Array)
#9 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(596): yii\base\Module->createControllerByID('assignment')
#10 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(588): yii\base\Module->createController('')
#11 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(522): yii\base\Module->createController('')
#12 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('rbac', Array)
#13 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('rbac', Array)
#14 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#15 /var/www/imgsrv/yii(23): yii\base\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

как исправить данную ошибку?

upd:

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;

class RbacController extends \yii\console\Controller {

    public function actionInit() {
        $auth = \Yii::$app->authManager;
        $auth->removeAll();

        $user = $auth->createRole('user');
        $user->description = 'Обычный пользователь';
        $auth->add($user);

        $fabricator = $auth->createRole('fabricator');
        $fabricator->description = 'Производитель';
        $auth->add($fabricator);

        $photograph = $auth->createRole('photograph');
        $photograph->description = 'Фотограф';
        $auth->add($photograph);

        $mentor = $auth->createRole('mentor');
        $mentor->description = 'Ментор';
        $auth->add($mentor);

        $moderator = $auth->createRole('moderator');
        $moderator->description = 'Модератор';
        $auth->add($moderator);

        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $admin->description = 'Администратор';
        $auth->add($admin);

        $superadmin = $auth->createRole('superadmin');
        $superadmin->description = 'СуперАдминистратор';
        $auth->add($superadmin);

        $fabricatorRule = new \common\rbac\FabricatorRule;
        $auth->add($fabricatorRule);

        $updateFabricatorImages = $auth->createPermission('updateFabricatorImages');
        $updateFabricatorImages->description = 'Редактирование изображений, принадлежащих производителю продукта';
        $updateFabricatorImages->ruleName = $fabricatorRule->name;
        $auth->add($updateFabricatorImages);

        $mentorRule = new \common\rbac\MentorRule;
        $auth->add($mentorRule);

        $mentorManage = $auth->createPermission('mentorManage');
        $mentorManage->description = 'Управление аккаунтами производителя';
        $mentorManage->ruleName = $fabricatorRule->name;
        $auth->add($mentorManage);


        $auth->addChild($fabricator, $user);
        $auth->addChild($fabricator,$updateFabricatorImages);

        $auth->addChild($photograph, $user);

        $auth->addChild($mentor, $fabricator);
        $auth->addChild($mentor,$mentorManage);

        $auth->addChild($moderator, $fabricator);
        $auth->addChild($moderator, $photograph);

        $auth->addChild($admin, $moderator);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $mentor);

        $auth->addChild($superadmin, $admin);
    }
}
```

upd2

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\console\Request::getMethod()'

in /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:300

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/VerbFilter.php(99): yii\base\Component->__call('getMethod', Array)
#1 [internal function]: yii\filters\VerbFilter->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#2 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(627): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(274): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#5 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(155): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#6 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#7 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('rbac', Array)
#8 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('rbac', Array)
#9 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#10 /var/www/imgsrv/yii(23): yii\base\Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

upd3 ранее я переопределял модель users и переименовывал в user, а так же добавил кучу проверок rbac.

Comment: Вы пытаете вызвать Yii::$app->user() ?

Comment: @АндрейДобровольский, я пытаюсь вызвать Yii::$app->authManager

Comment: я уверен на 85% что ошибка связана с вызовом через консоль, т.к. не возможно получить текущего юзера через консоль.

Comment: и как тогда мне инициализировать роли? и я не пытаюсь получить юзера, привел код инициализирующего класса

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у вас вообще какой-то другой контроллер вызывается. Добавьте в вопрос ваш конфиг console\config\main и как вы вызываете вашу команду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исправил костылем - делаю инициализацию через миграции. (ответ дан 1 ноя в 7:40 )

upd: так понял в чем ошибка.

в  `common/config/main.php` были подключены модули `gii`,`rbac` и `debug`.

перекинул их в конфиг фронтеда и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в **config\console.php** (для basic) или **console\config\main** (для advanced) и там определите модель отвечающую за юзера

```
 'components' => [
  .........
   ......
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'session' => [ // for use session in console application
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session'
    ],
 .......
]
```

Comment: не помогло, дополнил вопрос. вообще мне нужно получать юзера, я даже не знаю где он вызывается. ни  где не определял вроде

Comment: и у меня advanced шаблон